# Actionbar home/up button actual id differs from R.id.home

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a ridiculous problem! I want to handle action home button, but `MenuItem` passed to `onOptionsItemSelected` method when i tap home button is not `R.id.home`(nor `R.id.homeAsUp`).

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.v("1111", "MenuItem id: "+id);
    Log.v("1111", "home id: "+R.id.home);
    Log.v("1111", "homeAsUp id: "+R.id.homeAsUp);
    ...
    }
```

Log:

```
11-19 23:58:56.433: V/1111(30059): MenuItem id: 16908332
11-19 23:58:56.433: V/1111(30059): home id: 2131296256
11-19 23:58:56.433: V/1111(30059): homeAsUp id: 2131296270
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the '**android**' prefix. The Up button's `id` is `android.R.id.home` actually, not `R.id.home`.

Comment: Cheers! I believe this is a case of dodgy android studio java code to kotlin conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You handle home button like

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id==android.R.id.home){
         /*Do your code here*/
    }
}
```